# Fragment managment android

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I want to pass from a fragment of the navigation drawer menu to a fragment outside of the menu. I manage to display the new fragment but overriden to the previous. Can you suggest me some link?

```
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction t1 = manager.beginTransaction();
    DetailFragment instance = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
    b2.putString("Title", Title);
    b2.putString("author", author);
    instance.setArguments(b2);
    t1.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, instance);
    t1.commit();
```

The problem is the R.id.nav_host_fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void routine(String Title, String author,Fragment fragment,FragmentManager f1) {

    FragmentTransaction t1 = f1.beginTransaction();
    DetailFragment instance = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
    b2.putString("Title", Title);
    b2.putString("author", author);
    instance.setArguments(b2);
    t1.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    t1.replace(fragment.getId(), instance,"Change layout");
    t1.commit();
}
```

The above function is recall by my first fragment in the code below to pass to the next fragment where the first fragment is come from nav bar fragment and the next fragment is an empty fragment

```
                    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment fragment =getParentFragment();
                    instance.routine(Title[position],Author[position],fragment,
                            instance.getSupportFragmentManager());
```